# Swift crashes every memory address jump

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

This has been haunting me over the past three hours and I don't seem to get my head around it.

I have the following IBOutlet:

```
@IBAction func simulateTheDay(sender: UIButton) {
    if( self.iceCubesUsing == 0 || self.lemonsUsing == 0){
        showAlertMessage(message: "You need to use at least one lemon or ice cube")
    }

    var numberOfCustomers = 0;
    var winnings = 0;

    self.lemonToIceCubeRatio = self.lemonsUsing / self.iceCubesUsing
    self.lemonsToPurchase = 0
    self.iceCubesToPurchase = 0
    self.lemonsUsing = 0
    self.iceCubesUsing = 0
    self.customers = [];

    do{
        numberOfCustomers = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(11)));
    }while( numberOfCustomers == 0)

    for(var i=0;i<numberOfCustomers;i++){
        self.customers.append(Customer(preference: Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(101)))/101.0))
    }
    winnings = standBrain.calculateWinnings(self.customers, acidity: self.lemonToIceCubeRatio)
    self.money += winnings

    updateAssets()
}
```

wherever self. is a global variable in my class.
Whenever I click on the button tied to this outlet, the application crashes and highlights my if() statement at the top, saying "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXCI386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

If I copy the same code into another IBAction it works perfectly. Here comes the weird bit. If I remove the if statement with its contents, it crashes at my while statement. If I remove that, it then crashes at my for statement. If I even remove that, it crashes at the end of the function, again with the same error message in all cases.

If I only leave:
`showAlertMessage(message: "You need to use at least one lemon or ice cube")` it doesnt seem to jump to my function.

I tried removing the IBOutlet and recreating it, tried creating a new UIButton in my storyboard, and linking it to a new IBOutlet, tried cleaning the project, tried clearing all settings and data at the iOS Simulator. Nothing seems to work.

Here is the previous stack trace if it's helpful at all.

```
LemonadeStand`@objc LemonadeStand.ViewController.simulateTheDay (LemonadeStand.ViewController)(ObjectiveC.UIButton) -> () at ViewController.swift:
0x10466a800:  pushq  %rbp
0x10466a801:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x10466a804:  subq   $0x30, %rsp
0x10466a808:  movq   %rdx, -0x8(%rbp)
0x10466a80c:  movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rdx
0x10466a810:  movq   %rdi, -0x10(%rbp)
0x10466a814:  movq   %rdx, %rdi
0x10466a817:  movq   %rsi, -0x18(%rbp)
0x10466a81b:  movq   %rdx, -0x20(%rbp)
0x10466a81f:  callq  0x10466e1a4               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
0x10466a824:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rdi
0x10466a828:  movq   %rax, -0x28(%rbp)
0x10466a82c:  callq  0x10466e1a4               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
0x10466a831:  movq   -0x20(%rbp), %rdi
0x10466a835:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
0x10466a839:  movq   %rax, -0x30(%rbp)
0x10466a83d:  callq  0x10466a0e0               ;     LemonadeStand.ViewController.simulateTheDay (LemonadeStand.ViewController)(ObjectiveC.UIButton) -> () at ViewController.swift:65
0x10466a842:  addq   $0x30, %rsp
0x10466a846:  popq   %rbp
0x10466a847:  retq
```

**Edit:** Added my button's attributes

[image: Start Day Button Code]

Comment: can you add your button properties ?

Comment: I modified the question to add the connection properties of my button.

Comment: Just a hunch. Change the name of showAlertMessage to something else , say myShowAlertMessage

Comment: Nope. Still crashes on the same place.. This is really getting on my nerves now.. It's the weirdest thing I've come across.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct attributes here ?

[image]